# vim search and replace command to replace `(*,*)` with nothing

Tags: regular-expression, vim, search, fortran

I'm reworking some Fortran code. I need to remove the pattern `(*,*)` using vim's search and replace function. The following does not work

```
%s/\<(*,*)\>//gc
%s/\<(*\,*)\>//gc
%s/(*,*)//gc
```

the last one only removes the contents between the parentheses and not the parentheses themselves

Comment: Did this answer work. If so the tick the ✓.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to escape the `*` as `\*`.  The `*` is special in regular expressions and means *match the previous thing zero or more times*.

The substitution in Vim would be

```
:%s/(\*,\*)//g
```

---

If you unset the `magic` option in Vim, with

```
:set nomagic
```

then *only* the `^` ("start of line") and `$` ("end of line") characters have special meaning in regular expressions.

This means that the substitution

```
:%s/(*,*)//g
```

would do what you'd like it to do.

Most people do want to have the `magic` option set though (and it is set by default in Vim).

Comment: Small addition: If you want to unset magic only for one expression, you can just add a `\v`, `\V`, `\M` inside your expression :)